# Boost space in path not being handled correctly

Tags: c++, boost, process

I'm using the Boost process header and I can't seem to get the boost::process::system to take in my .cpp file path due to a space in the directory.

```
auto path = bp::search_path("g++");
int result = bp::system(path, "\"C:\\Users\\Sachin Chopra\\Documents\\rchat\\console_process\\src\\main.cpp\"");
```

I get the following error when I execute my code:

```
g++.exe: error: "C:\Users\Sachin: Invalid argument
g++.exe: error: Chopra\Documents\rchat\console_process\src\main.cpp": No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
```

The file path formatting works for me .exe file, and will launch from boost if I use it. e.g.

```
bp::system("\"C:\\Users\\Sachin Chopra\\Documents\\rchat\\build\\console_process\\consoleproc.exe\"");
```

But when I introduce the g++ path, it seems to mess up. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Looking at the g++ docs (https://www.cs.bu.edu/fac/gkollios/cs113/Usingg++.html), you can't just pass a file, you need some param first. Try  bp::system(path, "-c" , ...)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! I tried this and I'm still getting the same error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing shell script with the `system` interface.

You can either use old style, error-prone `system`:

```
bp::system(R"(bash -c "echo hello; echo world")");
```

Or you can pass raw arguments instead of relyng on shell escaping

```
bp::system(bp::search_path("bash"),
           std::vector<std::string>{
               "-c",
               "echo foo; echo bar",
           });
```

Which could also be written more like

```
bp::system(bp::search_path("bash"), "-c", "echo 42; echo answer");
```

In fact, you should probably use the `bp::child` interace instead of the
`system` compatible one:

```
bp::child compiler_job(
    bp::search_path("g++"),
    R"(C:\Users\Sachin Chopra\Documents\rchat\console_process\src\main.cpp)");

compiler_job.wait_for(5s);
if (compiler_job.running()) {
    compiler_job.terminate();
}

int result = compiler_job.exit_code();
std::cout << "compiler_job exit_code: " << result << "\n";
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6898ee9ee874f519)**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace bp = boost::process;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    // either use old style, error-prone system
    bp::system(R"(bash -c "echo hello; echo world")");

    // or pass raw arguments instead of relyng on shell escaping
    bp::system(bp::search_path("bash"),
               std::vector<std::string>{
                   "-c",
                   "echo foo; echo bar",
               });

    // Which can aslo be written as
    bp::system(bp::search_path("bash"), "-c", "echo 42; echo answer");

    // in fact, you should probably use the `bp::child` interace instead of the
    // `system` compatible one:
    bp::child compiler_job(
        bp::search_path("g++"),
        R"(C:\Users\Sachin Chopra\Documents\rchat\console_process\src\main.cpp)");

    compiler_job.wait_for(5s);
    if (compiler_job.running()) {
        compiler_job.terminate();
    }

    int result = compiler_job.exit_code();
    std::cout << "compiler_job exit_code: " << result << "\n";
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
hello
world
foo
bar
42
answer
g++: error: C:\Users\Sachin Chopra\Documents\rchat\console_process\src\main.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
compiler_job exit_code: 1
```